# Algorithm for the maximum absolute sub array sum under threshold value

Tags: arrays, algorithm, performance

What I am trying to convey with the title is the following exercise:
One is given an list of numbers both positive and negative where 0 < N < 100 000. From this list one needs to find the maximum sub array sum, but it should be the maximum sum under a certain threshold value (x). The exercise is meant to be solved in c++, but that doesn't really matter. Also the naive approach which is O(n^2) isn't fast enough with the time constraints given. I also couldn't think of a simple approach to make this work like there is with the maximum sub array sum.

For example:
The list: 1 -4 5 6 -3 -2 14

If the threshold is 4, the best solution would be `{-4}`

If the threshold is 9, the best solution would be `{-3 -2 14}`

If the threshold is 100, the best solution would be `{5 6 -3 -2 14}`

If the threshold is 7, the best solution would be `{-4 5 6}`

If the threshold is 2, the best solution would be `{-2}`

For the people who are interested in how I approached the problem:

The O(n^2) solution I used just looped over every possible sub array sum. It did not recalculate every sum rather it just add a new number it came across.

Comment: You're problem must probably be solved by a recursive way.

Comment: But recursive solutions usually are not the fastest. I am having a feeling there is some trick or data structure which can help in this case. As of yet I have not found such trick or structure.

Comment: You should provide a part of your structure in order to help people who could answer to visualize your problem.

Comment: You mean the code that was to slow? Or an example of what is actually wanted?

Comment: "If the threshold is 4, the best solution would be `{-4}`" and "If the threshold is 2, the best solution would be `{-2}`", why? Shouldn't it be `{1}` in both cases?

Comment: Maybe threshold isn't the right word then. The answer should be less or equal to the threshold and it is the absolute value. So a sum of -4 becomes 4 and -2 will be 2

Comment: @Yadeses So, given a sequence `s` and a positive threshold value `t`, you need to find a subsequence `r` that minimizes `t - abs(sum(r))` having `t >= abs(sum(r))`, is that right, or is it something else?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute partial sums: `P(i) = sum(a[0]...a[i])`

For a given position pair x, y (x <= y) the sum is `P(y) - P(x-1)`.
So if we fix y, then you are looking for the smallest value greater or equal to y - target.

So iterate over the set and insert items into balanced tree (like set in most languages). Then you can lookup the value in the set and return the value (in C++ there's upper_bound that does almost exactly what you need). Keep doing this and find the largest combination that satisfies the condition.

Lookup, and insertion should be O(log N) so overall the solution is going to be O(N logN).

Comment: I would like to add that one has to check for both options, because of the answer is the absolute of the sum.

`|(P(y) - P(x-1)| <= target`

`P(y) - P(x-1) <= target v P(y) - P(x-1) >= -target`

`P(x-1) <= P(y) - target v P(x-1) >= P(y) + target`

Hopefully that is understandable.